# How can I add background color beyond the container in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add background color beyond the container in CSS.

But the problem I am facing is: it overlaps the container and I am unable to show background before the container.

HTML code is here

```
<div class="container">Some content here </div>
```

And CSS code

```
    .container { padding: 15px; background-color: #eee; 
 /* For centering the container */
        margin: 0 auto; }
    /* CSS for background before the container */
    .container::before { content: "";
    background-color: red;
    width: 300%;
    height: auto;
    left: -100%;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    }
```

Please let me know what mistake I am doing.

Comment: You have `<div class="container>` in your HTML in the question. Is that intentional or did you mean `<div class="container">` and you just mistyped it here?

Comment: add `z-index:-1` to the pseudo element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `height` on the `:before` so the background is not visible:

```css
.container {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin:50px;
}
.container:before { content: "";
  background-color: red;
  width: 300%;
  height: auto;
  left: -100%;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Some content here</div>
```